# Trying to set useLegacyDatetimeCode to false in MySQL fails

Tags: mysql, jdbc

When I set useLegacyDatetimeCode=false in my JDBC connection properties, I get this error message:

> java.sql.SQLException: The server timezone value 'CET' represents more
>   than one timezone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver
>   (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc
>   timezone value if you want to utilize timezone support. The timezones
>   that 'CET' maps to are: Europe/Tirane, Europe/Andorra, Europe/Vienna,
>   Europe/Minsk, Europe/Brussels, Europe/Sofia, Europe/Prague,
>   Europe/Copenhagen, Europe/Tallinn, Europe/Berlin, Europe/Gibraltar,
>   Europe/Athens, Europe/Budapest, Europe/Rome, Europe/Riga,
>   Europe/Vaduz, Europe/Vilnius, Europe/Luxembourg, Europe/Malta,
>   Europe/Chisinau, Europe/Tiraspol, Europe/Monaco, Europe/Amsterdam,
>   Europe/Oslo, Europe/Warsaw, Europe/Lisbon, Europe/Kaliningrad,
>   Europe/Madrid, Europe/Stockholm, Europe/Zurich, Europe/Kiev,
>   Europe/Uzhgorod, Europe/Zaporozhye, Europe/Simferopol,
>   Europe/Belgrade, Africa/Algiers, Africa/Tripoli, Africa/Casablanca,
>   Africa/Tunis, Africa/Ceuta.

I understand what the message is telling me, but I'm not sure what to do about it. I don't have any way of knowing what time zone the MySQL server is running in (this is software that my customers install, and the servers are not managed by me).

I need to set this property to false to fix MySQL time zone bugs.

Comment: It's a bug in the connector. Check this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26515700/mysql-jdbc-driver-5-1-33-time-zone-issue/33893008#33893008

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass an additional parameter like this:

```
db=jdbc:mysql://localhost/db?user=me&pass=secret&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=Europe/Vienna
```