# Spring MVC with Hibernate - Transaction exception

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions, hibernate-entitymanager, spring-orm

I got exception while try insert data to MySQL with Hibernate JPA in Spring MVC. I have a this exception:

```
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:431)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:427)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:276)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy63.insertData(Unknown Source)
    at az.mrbee.services.UseJpaServiceImpl.inserDataYoxla(UseJpaServiceImpl.java:22)
    at az.mrbee.controllers.UseJpaController.useInsertData(UseJpaController.java:25)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:832)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:743)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:895)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:858)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:284)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:263)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:174)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:793)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1692)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1602)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1700)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:48)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.beginTransaction(HibernateJpaDialect.java:170)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:380)
    ... 53 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getConnectionForTransactionManagement(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:227)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.begin(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.begin(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1525)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:45)
    ... 55 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (The server time zone value 'Azerbaijan Standard Time' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2294)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:2039)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1533)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:386)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:84)
    ... 62 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: The server time zone value 'Azerbaijan Standard Time' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:695)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:663)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:653)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:638)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:606)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:624)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:620)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:68)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:1683)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:656)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:349)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:221)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:39)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:256)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2304)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2290)
    ... 67 more
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.InvalidConnectionAttributeException: The server time zone value 'Azerbaijan Standard Time' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:54)
    at com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:73)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.util.TimeUtil.getCanonicalTimezone(TimeUtil.java:118)
    at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.MysqlaSession.configureTimezone(MysqlaSession.java:308)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.initializePropsFromServer(ConnectionImpl.java:2474)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:1817)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:1673)
    ... 74 more
18:30:48,432 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-4) UT005023: Exception handling request to /DdTestProject/use/insert: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:979)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:858)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:284)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:263)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:174)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:793)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:431)        
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy63.insertData(Unknown Source)
    at az.mrbee.services.UseJpaServiceImpl.inserDataYoxla(UseJpaServiceImpl.java:22)
    at az.mrbee.controllers.UseJpaController.useInsertData(UseJpaController.java:25)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:832)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:743)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:895)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1692)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1602)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1700)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:48)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.beginTransaction(HibernateJpaDialect.java:170)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:380)
    ... 53 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getConnectionForTransactionManagement(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:227)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.begin(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.begin(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:52)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (The server time zone value 'Azerbaijan Standard Time' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.)
```

My Web Application Initialize :

```
public class WebAppInit extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[]{MyRootApplicationContext.class};
    }

    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[]{MyDispServ.class};
    }

    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }
}
```

I am using Root Application Context for configure Jpa configure:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource("classpath:conn.properties")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "az.mrbee.daos")
public class MyRootApplicationContext {

    @Autowired
    Environment env;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource(){
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("db.driverClass"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("db.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("db.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("db.password"));

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter(){
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        jpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
        jpaVendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.MYSQL);

        return jpaVendorAdapter;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean(){
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        emf.setDataSource(dataSource());
        emf.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter());
        emf.setPackagesToScan("az.mrbee.entities");

        return emf;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory){
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }

    @Bean
    public BeanPostProcessor persistenceTranslator(){
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

}
```

Entity Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "yoxla")
@XmlRootElement
public class Yoxla implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private int ID;

    @Column(name = "ad")
    private String ad;

    @Column(name = "val")
    private double val;


    public int getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public void setID(int ID) {
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    public String getAd() {
        return ad;
    }

    public void setAd(String ad) {
        this.ad = ad;
    }

    public double getVal() {
        return val;
    }

    public void setVal(double val) {
        this.val = val;
    }
}
```

After configure first time I used @Repository class directly in @Controller but I got Transaction error. After that used this one:

```
public interface UseJpaDAO {

    public Yoxla insertData(Yoxla y);
}
```

---

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class UseJpaDAOImpl  implements UseJpaDAO{

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Transactional
    public Yoxla insertData(Yoxla y) {
        em.persist(y);
        return y;
    }
}
```

---

```
public interface UseJpaService {
    Yoxla inserDataYoxla();    
}
```

---

```
@Service
public class UseJpaServiceImpl implements UseJpaService {

    @Autowired
    private UseJpaDAO jpaDAO;

    public Yoxla inserDataYoxla() {
        Yoxla y = new Yoxla();
        y.setAd("sdsda");
        y.setVal(1212);
        jpaDAO.insertData(y);
        return y;
    }
}
```

That is all. After all of that when I try to use this service in Controller I get exception

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/use")
public class UseJpaController {

    @Autowired
    UseJpaService useJpaService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/insert")
    public @ResponseBody String useInsertData(){
        useJpaService.inserDataYoxla();
        return "Everything is okay";
    }
}
```

### Solution:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost/db?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
```

Comment: this is a time zone issue, and it is a bug in mysql-connector-java from version 5.1.33 up to 5.1.37 see this question it might help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26515700/mysql-jdbc-driver-5-1-33-time-zone-issue

Comment: Thanks man. You saved my life :) This exception killed me in two days.