# Spring Tomcat With Mysql Database Error

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jdbc, spring-jdbc

I am getting error when i call the database using jdbc template.
Any problem in my code please help me..

Error :`Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server.
Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server.`

My context code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.1.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.dmask" />
<context:annotation-config />

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url"
        value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dmask?useSSL=true" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="admin" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="bCryptPasswordEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder" />
```

If anybody know that please help me..

Comment: It might be easier to help if you show the *full* stacktrace.

Comment: Thanks.My problem is fixed.Reference Link :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26515700/mysql-jdbc-driver-5-1-33-time-zone-issue

Answer (score 0):

This may help :

```
<util:map id="dbProps">
    <entry key="db.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <entry key="db.jdbcurl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/world"/>
    <entry key="db.username" value="myuser"/>
    <entry key="db.password" value="mypass"/>
</util:map>


<bean id="dataSource"
       class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${db.driver}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${db.jdbcurl}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${db.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${db.password}"/>
</bean>

<bean
 class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="properties" ref="dbProps"/>
</bean>
```

Refered from :
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-usagenotes-spring-config.html