# server timezone value 'X' is unrecognized or represents more than one timezone

Tags: java, windows, jdbc, schemacrawler

I'm trying to use [SchemaCrawler](http://sualeh.github.io/SchemaCrawler/) against a MySQL database (version 5.6.17). The specific SchemaCrawler command I'm running from Windows CMD is:

```
schemacrawler.cmd -server=mysql -database=mydb -infolevel=minimum -command=list -loglevel=CONFIG -u=myname
```

From this command I'm getting:

```
... server timezone value 'X' is unrecognized or represents more than one timezone
```

Where `X` is a timezone string like ETD.

In [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26515700/mysql-jdbc-driver-5-1-33-time-zone-issue), answer seems to be using `serverTimezone` parameter in the connection string. But, In my case, as a SchemaCrawler user, I cannot modify the connection string.

How should I proceed?

Comment: Try /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe --timezone=UTC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SchemaCrawler](http://sualeh.github.io/SchemaCrawler/) offers an alternate version of the command-line, where you can use the database connection URL as described in the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26515700/mysql-jdbc-driver-5-1-33-time-zone-issue) that you mention. Simply substitute `-database=mydb` with `-url=...`.

Sualeh Fatehi, [SchemaCrawler](http://sualeh.github.io/SchemaCrawler/)