# Error. Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, maven, jdbc

I try to connect to the mysql database for simple CRUD with Tomcat9 and Hibernate.

the exception is following:

```
type Exception report
message Unable to create requested service        [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from  fulfilling this request.

exception

org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:267)
org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:231)
org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:240)
org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:418)
org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:87)
org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:691)
org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:726)
serviceImpl.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:13)
serviceImpl.HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:19)
serviceImpl.CarServiceImpl.add(CarServiceImpl.java:10)
controller.CarController.doGet(CarController.java:25)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)

root cause

org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error calling Driver#connect
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator$1$1.convert(BasicConnectionCreator.java:105)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.convertSqlException(BasicConnectionCreator.java:123)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:41)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:58)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.addConnections(PooledConnections.java:123)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:42)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:20)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections$Builder.build(PooledConnections.java:161)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildPool(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:109)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:72)
org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:240)
org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:257)
org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:231)
org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:240)
org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:418)
org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:87)
org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:691)
org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:726)
serviceImpl.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:13)
serviceImpl.HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:19)
serviceImpl.CarServiceImpl.add(CarServiceImpl.java:10)
controller.CarController.doGet(CarController.java:25)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)

root cause

java.sql.SQLException: The server time zone value 'RTZ 2 (����)' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:545)
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:513)
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:505)
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:479)
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:489)
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:69)
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:1606)
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:633)
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:347)
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:219)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:38)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:58)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.addConnections(PooledConnections.java:123)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:42)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:20)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections$Builder.build(PooledConnections.java:161)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildPool(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:109)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:72)
org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:240)
org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:257)
org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:231)
org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:240)
org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:418)
org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:87)
org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:691)
org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:726)
serviceImpl.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:13)
serviceImpl.HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:19)
serviceImpl.CarServiceImpl.add(CarServiceImpl.java:10)
controller.CarController.doGet(CarController.java:25)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)

root cause

com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.InvalidConnectionAttributeException: The server time zone value 'RTZ 2 (����)' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:54)
com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:73)
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.util.TimeUtil.getCanonicalTimezone(TimeUtil.java:118)
com.mysql.cj.mysqla.MysqlaSession.configureTimezone(MysqlaSession.java:293)
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.initializePropsFromServer(ConnectionImpl.java:2399)
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:1739)
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:1596)
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:633)
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:347)
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:219)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:38)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:58)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.addConnections(PooledConnections.java:123)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:42)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:20)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections$Builder.build(PooledConnections.java:161)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildPool(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:109)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:72)
org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:240)
org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:257)
org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:231)
org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:240)
org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:418)
org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:87)
org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:691)
org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:726)
serviceImpl.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:13)
serviceImpl.HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:19)
serviceImpl.CarServiceImpl.add(CarServiceImpl.java:10)
controller.CarController.doGet(CarController.java:25)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
```

The configuration-file is:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb</property>
<property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
<mapping class="entity.Car"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Hibernate Util:

```
package serviceImpl;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistryBuilder;

public class HibernateUtil {
private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
private static ServiceRegistry sersviceRegistry;

static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure();
        sersviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();
        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(sersviceRegistry);
        return sessionFactory;
    }

/*public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}*/

}
```

Car service:

```
package serviceImpl;

import entity.Car;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import service.CarService;

public class CarServiceImpl implements CarService {
public void add(Car car){
    Session session = HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(car);
    transaction.commit();
    session.close();
}
}
```

Servlet:

```
package controller;

import entity.Car;
import serviceImpl.CarServiceImpl;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

@WebServlet("/car")
public class CarController extends HttpServlet {
Car car = new Car();
CarServiceImpl carServiceImpl = new CarServiceImpl();

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    if(request.getParameter("add") != null) {
        String name = request.getParameter("name");
        String model = request.getParameter("model");
        car.setName(name);
        car.setModel(model);
        carServiceImpl.add(car);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("add.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
}
}
```

JSP

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
<title>JSPLab</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="add">
<h1>Add car</h1>
<form action="CarController" method="GET">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td> Car name: </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="name"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> Car model: </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="model"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" name="add" value="add">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Maven dependencies

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>labjsp</groupId>
<artifactId>labjsp</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.5.Final</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>servletexam</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

</project>
```

The architecture of the project

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YzIjm.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL JDBC Driver 5.1.33 - Time Zone Issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26515700/mysql-jdbc-driver-5-1-33-time-zone-issue)

Answer (score 1):

Obviously I am late here to answer, Still answering this question in the case if some one encounters same error.

I also had same problem, and the reason in my case was I forgot to create the database.

so better check if you have created database or not and have you created user and granted permissions or not ?