# Malformed database URL, failed to parse the main URL sections

Tags: java, mysql

```
package miniproject;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class Mysql_connection {

    private Connection con=null;
    private Statement st=null;
    private ResultSet res=null;
    public Mysql_connection() {
    try{        
            //Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

            con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql:‪//localhost:3306/miniprojectdb","root","");
            st=con.createStatement();

    }catch(SQLException e)
    {
        System.out.println("SQLException: "+ e.getMessage());
        System.out.println("SQLState: "+ e.getSQLState());
        System.out.println("VendorError"+ e.getErrorCode());   
    }
    }
    public void Data(){
    try{        
        String query="select * from produit";
        res=st.executeQuery(query);
        System.out.println("========================="); 
        while(res.next()){
            int a=res.getInt(1);
            String b=res.getString(2);
            int c=res.getInt(3);
            System.out.println("ProdID:"+a+" "+"ProdNom:"+b+" "+"Prix/Tonne:"+c);
        }
    }catch(Exception e){ 
        System.out.println(e);  
    }   
    }

}
```

I'm getting this Error:

> SQLException: Cannot load connection class because of underlying
>   exception: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.WrongArgumentException: Malformed
>   database URL, failed to parse the main URL sections.
>
> SQLState: 08001
>
> VendorError0

I'm using this (`C:\Users\ABDOU NASSER\Desktop\mysql-connector-java-8.0.11\mysql-connector-java-8.0.11.jar`) with the last eclipse version 2018
and as database XAMPP (MySQL)

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's an invisible character between `mysql:` and `//localhost` in your JDBC URL. You can check it here:

https://www.soscisurvey.de/tools/view-chars.php

This shows the string as:

```
jdbc:mysql:‪U+202A//localhost:3306/miniprojectdb
```

This `U+202A` character is [LEFT-TO-RIGHT EMBEDDING](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/202a/index.htm).

Comment: @AbdouNasserChan Here you go: `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/miniprojectdb`

Comment: nice but it generate me a new error is :SQLException: The server time zone value 'Maroc (heure dÂ?Ã©tÃ©)' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.
SQLState: 01S00
VendorError0

Comment: @AbdouNasserChan This is a separate question. Your original question is answered.

Comment: yes thank you for help but if you only can help me with this also i will be thankful

Comment: @AbdouNasserChan I don't use MySQL and don't have much experience with it but the error message tells you what to do.

Comment: ok now i fixed the last error and connect successfully by adding this                                                             ("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/miniprojectdb?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC","root","");                          i got it from here:
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26515700/mysql-jdbc-driver-5-1-33-time-zone-issue

Answer (score 4):

You have a space in jdbc connection URL, remove that space and try again:

```
jdbc:mysql:‪//localhost:3306/miniprojectdb
-----------^
```