# MySQL connector error "The server time zone value Central European Time"

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

**My problem**

MySQL connector "The server time zone value Central European Time" is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone.

**The project**

Small web Project with:
JavaEE, Tomcat 8.5, MySQL, Maven

**My attempt**

- Maven -> change MySQL-connector form 6.x to 5.1.39 (no change)
- Edit context.xml URL change

Connection in context.xml

URL="jdbc: mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/rk_tu_lager?**useLegacyDatetimeCode=false;serverTimezone=CEST;useSSL=false;**

**Error:**

> Caused by:
>   com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.InvalidConnectionAttributeException:  The
>   server time zone value 'Mitteleurop?ische Sommerzeit' is unrecognized
>   or  represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the
>   server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property)
>   to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone
>   support.

Comment: Is CEST a valid value for this property? What happens if you use - for example - `Europe/Amsterdam` instead?

Comment: with "Europe/Amsterdam" no change

Comment: the new error: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (No timezone mapping entry for 'Europe/Amsterdam;

Comment: Interesting, I think you'll need to wait for someone with more day-to-day experience with MySQL.

Comment: The trailing semicolon in `'Europe/Amsterdam;` looks suspicious. Try separating your connection string argument pairs with `&` instead of `;`.

Comment: Thank you, you are great

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Thank you Mark Rotteveel and Gord Thompson

I have the connection in an XML file, with `&amp;` and `Europe/Amsterdam` finally works.

```java
url="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/rk_tu_lager?useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&amp;serverTimezone=Europe/Amsterdam&amp;useSSL=false"
```

Thank you, you are great

Comment: Had the same problem in DataGrip and could solve it using a similar setting value. Setting it to `serverTimezone=Europe/Berlin` got me rid of the warning on connect.

Answer (score 11):

I faced this issue when I upgraded my mysql server to SQL Server 8.0 (MYSQL80).

The simplest solution to this problem is just write the below command in your MYSQL Workbench -

```
  SET GLOBAL time_zone = '+5:30'
```

The value after the time-zone will be equal to GMT+/- Difference in your timezone. The above example is for India(GMT+5:30).
It will solve the issue.

Answer (score 9):

Find what is the timezone you are in and replace +00:00 with your timezone.

```sql
SET @@global.time_zone = '+00:00';
SET @@session.time_zone = '+00:00';
```

Then check if the values were set:

```sql
SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone;
```

[image: SELECT result]

Answer (score 2):

If you are using MySQL client eg. DBeaver you should change settings of your connection. So, click right click mouse on the connection and click Edit Connection. Then, edit your driver properties which are located under the "Connection settings", go to the bottom of settings and click "Add new property", add serverTimezone as your new property name and enter value eg. Europe/Warsaw. 
That's all.