# timezone issue while connecting with mysql via spring boot, whats equivalent of Mitteleuropäische Zeit

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, mysql-connector

I am getting following error while I am trying to connect with mysql:

```
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.InvalidConnectionAttributeException: The server time zone value 'Mitteleuropäische Zeit' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.
```

So as to receive below issue, I already went through [MySQL JDBC Driver 5.1.33 - Time Zone Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26515700/mysql-jdbc-driver-5-1-33-time-zone-issue)

I am using below mysql connector:

mysql
        mysql-connector-java
        8.0.11

and application property is as below:

```
db2.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://www<><>06/esystem?useSSL=false&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&useUnicode=trueuseLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=GMT+1
```

I have used CET and GMT+1 in place of serverTimezone, but no luck. Any resolution point, what can be timezone placeholder for "Mitteleuropäische Zeit"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change MySQL timezone in a database connection using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7605953/how-to-change-mysql-timezone-in-a-database-connection-using-java)

Comment: @SimonMartinelli - Yes, tried your suggestion but its still not helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As seen in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50493398/mysql-connector-error-the-server-time-zone-value-central-european-time), you should use [IANA timezone formats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones), like `Europe/Berlin`:

```
db2.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://www<><>06/esystem?useSSL=false&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&useUnicode=trueuseLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=Europe/Berlin
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Germany#IANA_time_zone_database