# Connection Exception In Jmeter

Tags: mysql, jdbc, jmeter

I am just setting up a JDBC connection using Jmeter and MySQL.
I downloaded the jar file and placed the same file in Lib folder of Jmeter.
After that, I created a JDBC Connection Configuration and JDBC request.
I have also added a View result tree listener.

When I am running the request getting following error:
**"Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (The server time zone value 'EDT' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.)"**[please refer to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tuh1k.png)

Comment: what's your jar version? see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26515700/mysql-jdbc-driver-5-1-33-time-zone-issue?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: mysql-connector-java-8.0.11.jar

Comment: try to add to database URL `?serverTimezone=UTC`

Comment: Thanks, It worked.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL you can define time zone in database URL, it is been reported as an issue [here](https://github.com/gephi/gephi/issues/1875)

You can add to JMeter's JDBC Database URL field at the end `?serverTimezone=UTC`

Comment: Can you please let me know that how to use the retrieved value from Database in an HTTP  login request?

 Currently, I am trying to log in with, two variables username and password, mentioned in JDBC request but not able to log in. Even I tried with username_1, password_1 but getting the same issue.

I am running these request in a single thread.

Comment: @Anil Kumar you can't, you must first set it in JDBC connection. If it's a new question, ask a new question with more details