# Multiple errors when trying to connect MySQL server to Spring Boot App STS

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-boot

I'm trying to make a connection to a MySQL server within Spring Boot, using Spring Tool Suite. Even though my database is running and the schema is created, I get the following error:

```
WARN 44756 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource  : Registered driver with driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver was not found, trying direct instantiation.

ERROR 44756 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool       : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.

WARN 44756 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.orm.jpa.DatabaseLookup           : Unable to determine jdbc url from datasource

WARN 44756 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator     : HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : The server time zone value 'PDT' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.

WARN 44756 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
```

I'm using the following application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/book-schema
spring.datasource.username=root spring.datasource.password=root1234
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

I'm not sure what's causing this issue.

Comment: add the application.properties,pom.xml and hibernate configuration file(if exists)

Comment: i have the application.properties file as follows: spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/book-schema
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root1234
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update          not sure about the hibernate config file?

Comment: mysql connector version  and spring boot version in pom.xml?

Comment: no version is specified!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding timezone like below.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/book-schema?serverTimezone=UTC
```

Refer [time-zone-issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26515700/mysql-jdbc-driver-5-1-33-time-zone-issue)

Comment: i believe this solves my issue as i am no longer receiving errors.i had read similar threads but was not able to track down a simple fix like so..THANKYOU !!

Comment: glad to help you..happy coding.