# java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database

Tags: java, mysql, database, maven, tomcat9

I've been trying to set up my own rest api for a school project. I decided to use MySQL as a database and i want to connect it with my webservice, but apparently i always get this error message: 
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/userdatenbank

When i look at the error message, it also tells me that this code can't be executed:

```
public UserService() {
    try {
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/userdatenbank", "root", "adminadmin123"); 
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }  
}
```

I don't know why this keeps happening... The MySQL Java Connector JAR-File is located in "Referenced Libraries". By the way I use Tomcat 9, MySQL 8, JDK 13 and Maven (Jersey Servlet).

Comment: If mysql-connector-java-*.jar is not available in the classpath then you cannot connect to the MySQL database ... you probably messed up the hierarchy of dependencies.

Comment: Sure you're not running MariaDB?  URL is different.

Comment: How do i tidy that hierarchy up?

Comment: No, i'm using MySQL and the server runs in the background.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before get connection you have to load your driver with:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

And the corresponding JAR must be in your classpath (in the lib of your server or packaged in your WAR file).

#### Update

As mentioned in @Silverfang's answer below, since JDBC 4.0, this statement is not longer required, as reported [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefjdbc4_0summary.html#:%7E:text=With%20JDBC%204.0%2C%20applications%20no,introduces%20refined%20subclasses%20of%20SQLException.)

#### Hints

Anyway I suggest you to use a [connection's pool](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-usagenotes-j2ee-concepts-connection-pooling.html) instead of `DriverManager`

> The main benefits to connection pooling are:
>
> 1. Reduced connection creation time.
>
> Although this is not usually an issue with the quick connection setup that MySQL offers compared to other databases, creating new JDBC connections still incurs networking and JDBC driver overhead that will be avoided if connections are recycled.
>
> 2. Simplified programming model.
>
> When using connection pooling, each individual thread can act as though it has created its own JDBC connection, allowing you to use straightforward JDBC programming techniques.
>
> 3. Controlled resource usage.
>
> If you create a new connection every time a thread needs one rather than using connection pooling, your application's resource usage can be wasteful, and it could lead to unpredictable behaviors for your application when it is under a heavy load.

Comment: The Class.forName() method doesn't change anything. Still an error. But this time i also have a java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver error.

Comment: If you have a ClassNotFound instead of SQLException, something is changed! As I wrote you must have a JAR containing the driver implementation in your class path

Comment: Do u mean the Java Connector jar-file? This one: mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar?

Comment: Yes, I do! You must have mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar in the lib of your server

Comment: Now i get this error: java.sql.SQLException: The server time zone value 'Mitteleurop?ische Zeit' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the 'serverTimezone' configuration property) to use a more specific time zone value. And also this error: org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Jersey Web Application] in context with path [/gfos-inno-award-2020] threw exception [java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/27276523/4210091

Comment: @Quantum, I am glad you found the solution useful. In these cases you can accept the solution by clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using maven just add the dependency in your pom.xml file.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>mysql</groupId>
<artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
<version>5.1.37</version>
```

Just go to the maven repo and search for a version that works for you.
or If you have downloaded the jar file then add it to your project classpath.

#### Edit

`Class.forName()` is not needed since JDBC 4.0; [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefjdbc4_0summary.html#:%7E:text=With%20JDBC%204.0%2C%20applications%20no,introduces%20refined%20subclasses%20of%20SQLException.) you can find the documentation related