# intelij idea adding mysql connector to project library

Tags: java, mysql, intellij-idea, jdbc, mysql-connector

I am trying to connect a mysql database to my java project, but I'm getting the error: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`

As seen in the image, I added mysql-connector-java-5.1.48.jar to my project, but it still gives me the error.

```
public static Connection getConnection(){
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            return DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error connecting to the database", ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException | ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;}
```

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:190)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:291)
    at DatabaseAccess.DbConnection.getConnection(DbConnection.java:17)
    at DatabaseAccess.DbConnection.main(DbConnection.java:27)
```

Comment: Are you using gradle, maven or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using maven, add this to your `<dependencies>` tag:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.19</version>
</dependency>
```

for gradle:

```
compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '8.0.19'
```

Comment: i use gradle, it seems to solve the problem. But now i got a different one.
 ```Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: The server time zone value 'West-Europa (standaardtijd)' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the 'serverTimezone' configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.
```

i looked at but don't understand how to change it
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26515700/mysql-jdbc-driver-5-1-33-time-zone-issue/44720416

Comment: @Mapijs this is a different problem, you can post is as another question:) Since my answer resolved your issue, you might consider upvoting it / marking as correct;>