# How to solve timezone error in Java EE project?

Tags: mysql, jsp, jdbc, timezone

I know that this question was discussed not for the first time, but they did not help me, please help (preferably in detail).
I have created an EE web project on intellij IDEA.
Connected with MySQL (photo below)
Then I write this code in
**index.jsp**

```
    <%
try
{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); //load driver
    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbuser","root","root"); //create connection
    
    if(request.getParameter("btn_login")!=null) //check login button click event not null
    {
        String dbemail,dbpassword;
        
        String email,password;
        
        email=request.getParameter("txt_email"); //txt_email
        password=request.getParameter("txt_password"); //txt_password
        
        PreparedStatement pstmt=null; //create statement
        
        pstmt=con.prepareStatement("select * from login where email=? AND password=?"); //sql select query 
        pstmt.setString(1,email);
        pstmt.setString(2,password);
        
        ResultSet rs=pstmt.executeQuery(); //execute query and store in resultset object rs.
        
        if(rs.next())
        {
            dbemail=rs.getString("email");
            dbpassword=rs.getString("password");
            
            if(email.equals(dbemail) && password.equals(dbpassword))
            {
                session.setAttribute("login",dbemail); //session name is login and store fetchable database email address
                response.sendRedirect("welcome.jsp"); //after login success redirect to welcome.jsp page
            }
        }
        else
        {
            request.setAttribute("errorMsg","invalid email or password"); //invalid error message for email or password wrong
        }
        
        con.close(); //close connection 
    }
    
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    out.println(e);
}
%>
```

[image: connection to DB]

And after running I have this error

> "The server time zone value 'Öåíòðàëüíàÿ Àçèÿ (çèìà)' is unrecognized
> or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the
> server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property)
> to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone
> support."

P.S: In Itellej IDEA time zone is `UTC` , and I'm also tried change in mysql

```
SET @@global.time_zone = '+00:00';
```

Comment: Hi check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27276523/10606400) answer might help .

Comment: @Swati I looked, but how exactly do I add to my code? Can you help with this

Comment: Change your connection string like `"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbuser?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC"` and see if that works .. Also that link has many suggesstion try other as well as see.

Comment: @Swati but in this line we must write also passwort to local server, so where I should write? 
 "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbuser?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC"

Comment: Just change `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbuser` to `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbuser?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC` in your code where you are passing connection string . Also ,password and username will be same no need to make any changes there.

Comment: @Swati Thank you very much, you helped so much. Pardon me.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbuser","root","root"); //create connection
```

must to rewrite to

```
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbuser?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC","root","root"); //create connection
```

[This post was helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26515700/mysql-jdbc-driver-5-1-33-time-zone-issue/27276523#27276523)